# Why "class not found"?

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpstorm, haxe

I have a controller which calls a static method in a class, I get this error:

```
[2015-03-02 08:03:13] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Main' not found' in D:\xampp\htdocs\motahida\app\controllers\DownloadWidgetController.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

the class Main, is at:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\motahida\app\controllers\haxe\bin\lib\Main.class.php
```

I call it like this:

```
Main::unzip("amjadTest.zip", "file out put", "");
```

from `DownloadWidgetController` class which is in:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\motahida\app\controllers\DownloadWidgetController.php
```

PhpStorm is not complaining about Main class, and it seems fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do a `composer dump-autoload` from your Laravel project folder to rebuild the autoloader class map

Comment: thanks, it worked :) how? shall dump-autoload each time I add a class?

Comment: Yes, get in the habit of doing it.... you can build most of your model/controller classes as stubs now, dump-autoload, then do the work on those models/controllers... which does save some time

Comment: @MarkBaker: It seems your comment should be an answer ;)

Comment: by the way, there are some file watchers tools, which can do an action whenever a file is added, this can be handy to call dump-autoload

Comment: *"phpstorm is not complaining about Main class, and it seems fine"* That's because PhpStorm checks classes by their names regardless of their location while your autoloader/PHP itself need to find actual file at expected location.

Comment: BTW -- the `composer dump-autoload` should not really be used at dev time (it's more targeted for production) -- your autoloader supposed to be able to find it without doing this / using standard instructions/config.

Comment: @MarkBaker He doesn't have to do that if he uses PSR-4 autoloading. Which is, unfortunately, not the standard in Laravel 4. Doesn't mean it can't be added though.